# iOS アプリ開発。Adhoc配布のアプリでPUSH通知が受信できない

Tags: ios, push-notification

お世話になります。

PUSH通知を使ったiOSアプリを開発しています。
通知は、AmazonのSNSサービスを利用しています。
今、Adhoc配布用に証明書やprovisioning profileを作り、アプリをビルド。
Macに接続した実機に対して、Xcodeから転送したアプリでは、Pusu通知が受信できる状態です。
ところが、同じアプリを、Adhoc配布すると、同端末なのにPUSH通知が受信できないで困っています。
ネット上の情報を調べると、そもそもそれができないのではないかという情報もあります。
情報をいただけたら幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 自己解決しました。
Amazon SNS管理画面にて、プッシュ通知プラットフォームとして開発版の「Apple iOS Dev」にしていました。これを、製品用の「Apple iOS Prod」にして登録したところ、受信できるようになりました。
拝見くださった方々、どうもありがとうございました。